# CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (GDAL error 1) after R update?

Tags: r, certificate, rstudio, raster, terra

Getting this error when trying to run some raster analysis:

**Warning messages:
1: PROJ: Cannot open https://cdn.proj.org/us_noaa_cohpgn.tif: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (GDAL error 1)
2: Network error when accessing a remote resource (GDAL error 1)**

Code:

```
library(raster)
library(trend)
library(terra)
library(zyp)

p.val.func <- function(x,na.rm=T) {
  if(sum(is.na(x)) == length(x)) return(NA)
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  unlist(sens.slope(x)[3]) 
}

sen.slope.func <- function(x,na.rm=T) {
  if(sum(is.na(x)) == length(x)) return(NA)
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  unlist(sens.slope(x)[1]) 
}

sens.int.func<- function(x,na.rm=T){
  if(sum(is.na(x)) == length(x)) return(NA)
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  y<-c()
  y<-c(1:nlyr(x))
  zyp.sen(x~y)$coefficients[1] 
}


# direct to all rasters
cov_rasters<- list.files("D:\\RAP_CO_ALL\\InputCoverStacks", full.names=T, pattern=".tif$")
r1<-rast(cov_rasters[1])  #load one for reprojecting the shp

shp<- vect("C:\\tmp\\GIS_projects_tmp\\UFO_test\\AlakaliCrkAllotsHUC10_AOI")


shp<- terra::project(shp, crs(r1)) # reproject
```

Session Info:
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

time zone: America/Denver
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.6-7   zyp_0.11-1    Kendall_2.2.1 terra_1.7-39  trend_1.1.5   raster_3.6-23 sp_2.0-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.5.1         codetools_0.2-19 lattice_0.21-8   remotes_2.4.2.1  grid_4.3.1       compiler_4.3.1   extraDistr_1.9.1 httr_1.4.7       boot_1.3-28.1    tools_4.3.1      curl_5.0.2
[12] Rcpp_1.0.11

Any solutions?

Tried restarting session

Comment: Warning comes on last line when reprojecting

Comment: personal firewall, company laptop, company network, or something else? does your ISP or local government impose firewalls?

Comment: @r2evans yes company laptop, same code was running fine earlier this week. There was some sort of patch update yesterday or day before (thanks for reminder) that I imagine may be a potential source of the problem